# How to get All Replies for particular Question of Discussion board using Sharepoint REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, discussion-board

I am able to get Questions from Discussion board using REST API.

Now I want to get its replies for particular Question using REST API.

I didn’t found any hint or example to get Replies using REST.

I have Some Additional Fields Columns in Discussion Board. Like some Text and some Lookup .

When I am give reply then its just give add data only in body part . but I want to Add all Items when user reply.

Second things is when I am Giving Reply from flat view it fill parentId  but not other fields.

And When i am add new Item in Reply view its provide view to add all column field  to fill but not Adding ParentID

Any help very Appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote you have already the particular question you need the replies for. Then you should now its ID as well. Using that ID you can filter the items for the replies for the particular question via REST (assuming the ID is 234):

```
http://YourServer/YourSite/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('TitleOfYourDiscussionBoard')/Items?$filter=ParentItemID eq 234
```

Note, that this query returns only the direct responses to the question, but not the replies for the responses.

To understand the other approach (returning any responses that belong to a question, independently from the position in the structure), you should first know, that dicsussion board threads are organized as a folder structure. The threads (the questions) are folders, and the answers for the questions are items within the corresponding folder.

You can get the folder objects for your question as:

```
http://YourServer/YourSite/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('TitleOfYourDiscussionBoard')/Items(234)/Folder
```

See the `ServerRelativeUrl` property of the returned item. Assume it is '`/YourSite/Lists/DiscussionBoard/Question234`'.

Next send a `POST` (not a `GET`!) request to the server with the URL below to get all items within the folder (that means, all answers for the particular question):

```
/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('DiscussionBoard')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={"ViewXml":"<View Scope='Recursive'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' /><Value Type='Text'>/YourSite/Lists/DiscussionBoard/Question234</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"}
```

Don't forget to escape the apostrophes in this text when using it in code as string!

```
var request = "/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('DiscussionBoard')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={\"ViewXml\":\"<View Scope='Recursive'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' /><Value Type='Text'>/YourSite/Lists/DiscussionBoard/Question234</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>\"}";
```

Alternatively (as long as you are working with `JavaScript` and not `C#`) you can build up a `JavaScript` object and stringify it via `JSON.stringify`.:

```
var query = {
    ViewXml: "<View Scope='Recursive'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' /><Value Type='Text'>/YourSite/Lists/DiscussionBoard/Question234</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
};

var request = "/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('DiscussionBoard')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1=" + JSON.stringify(query);
```

Comment: but what i am facing problem is i have some additional field columns. so when i give reply from flat view its just put in body column not other fields.

Comment: and if i am dding reply using new item its give  option to add all fileds but its not add parent ID

Comment: OK, now I understand your problem. Let's see if I can find something useful for you...

Comment: I know using this i can achieve this but i didnt get parent ID when i am adding using new items in reply view

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce your problem. The answers are created with a ParentID, either from the Flat view or the Threaded view. What do you mean on "reply view"? Could you write the name of its aspx page, please (like Flat.aspx for the Flat view)? If you create a new item, it will be created as a new discussion, of course without any parent and ParentID.

Comment: Reply view mean if i have click on parent its  show  all replay in that page if I create new Item manually . first i have make management view then click on item so its shows its replies. that view  i told replies view

Comment: As far as I see, if you switch to the Management view, then click on the New Item (either on the ribbon or above the existing threads) you will create a new question / thread. It has no parent, of course.

Comment: not in management view new item click. i want  to tell click on particular item so you redirect to new list in that create new item.

Comment: OK, it might behave differently in SharePoint Online. In my on-premise version I can not repro this step.