# Sharepoint REST API to retrieve discussion replies

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sharepoint-rest-api, error, discussion-board

I used below URL to retrieve list of replies for a discussion in SharePoint.

```
/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('DiscussionBoard')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={"ViewXml":"<View Scope='Recursive'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' /><Value Type='Text'>/YourSite/Lists/DiscussionBoard/Question234</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"}
```

Reference: [How to get All Replies for particular Question of Discussion board using Sharepoint REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190174/how-to-get-all-replies-for-particular-question-of-discussion-board-using-sharepo)

I am getting below error even though I passed the latest request digest.

The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again.

```
spReplies(topicUrl: any, requestDigest: any): Observable<any> { 
    var query = {
      ViewXml: '<View Scope="Recursive"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" /><Value Type="Text">' + topicUrl + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>'
    };
    
const url = weburl + '/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('DiscussionBoard')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1=' + JSON.stringify(query);
  
    return this.http.post(url,
       { headers: this.getHeaders(requestDigest), withCredentials: true });

}


private getHeaders(requestDigest: any) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; odata=verbose', 'X-RequestDigest': requestDigest });
    return headers;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the complete code you used for this? it will be helpful to understand what exactly the issue is.

Comment: Please check i have added the sample REST Service call and headers method

Comment: where and how you are defining `requestDigest` variable value? Are you doing this in SPFx webpart or somewhere else?

Comment: By sending POST request to weburl + "/_api/contextinfo" am getting request digest.